# Looping through each element in a DataRow

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

Basically, I have a `DataTable` as below:

[image]

I want to run a method per element per row which has the parameters

```
AddProductPrice(SKU, Price, PriceBracket)
```

As an example...:

If we take the first row of data, the method will be run a potential of 16 times, once for each time `Total Price X` isn't null.

So for the first total price in the first row the call will be:

```
AddProductPrice(SKU, <Total Price 1 value>, 1)
```

Then for the second total price in the first row the call will be:

```
AddProductPrice(SKU, <Total Price 2 value>, 2)
```

Please note: for the National Selling element the call would be:

```
AddProductPrice(SKU, <National Selling value>, 16)
```

Is there a clever way to loop through each element in a `DataRow` to make the procedure more efficient?

Comment: "*clever*" than what? What did *you* do?

Answer (score 19):

For each row, looping through the columns and then finding the index of "Total Price", "National Selling" and adding product price accordingly.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow myRow = dataTable.Rows[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            if (dataTable.Columns[j].ColumnName.IndexOf("Total Price") > 0)
            {
                AddProductPrice(SKU, myRow.ItemArray[j], j);
            }
            else if (dataTable.Columns[j].ColumnName.IndexOf("National Selling") > 0)
            {
                AddProductPrice(SKU, myRow.ItemArray[j], 16); //
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ItemArray` (type `object[]`) property of `DataRow` and iterate through its elements from column `tab.Columns.IndexOf("Trade Price 1")` to `tab.Columns.IndexOf("Trade Price 16")`.

Beware though, if the column order changes for some reason, your code could break. The safe way would be to iterate through items via an indexer - `row["Trade Price " + i]`.

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the DataTable.Columns Collection and parse based on the Column Name.

```
for(int i=0;i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
  if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.StartsWith("Total Price"))
  {
    var curBracket = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.SubString(11));
    AddProductPrice(SKU, curRow[dt.Columns[i].ColumnName, curBracket);
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Simon, I will try that out and see how it goes, do you have an email address incase I start having issues?